# What happen to a file when We read it and we just open it

Tags: python-3.x

I write code with and without **read**
I know that I can use readline, but would you please tell me what would happen to the file when I read it
I mean I assume with myself that to write any code I should read it at the first
just like a book when I Open and when I Read.
I get confused because I think with myself that with using **open** I do not access the content of the file
what did happen when I used **read**?[I put the image of my code with and without **read**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ymDy.png)

```
fn= input('Enter the file name:')
fno= open(fn)
lst = list()
for lines in fno:
    lines = lines.rstrip()
    word = lines.split()
    for w in word:
        if not w in last:
            lst.append(w)
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

Comment: I am  new to the site, so I do not know the rules thoroughly

Comment: I added code to my question

Comment: Would you please explain it to me?

Comment: You can find the site rules in the help section. Or check [ask]. That said, I'm not sure I understand what you want. Are you asking what the difference between opening a file and reading it is? Generally you need to open a file before you can read or write it. Access rights are checked when you open. The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) covers the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open` is kind-like accessing the file. If you like the book analogy: open is like finding the book in the library (directory) and accessing it, but without reading it first. Only `read` method is the one where you actually read the inside of the book, line by line.

During `open` method, your operating system locates the file and create a "connection" between your program and current file (I oversimplified it obviously). It allows to put this "connection" as a variable which you can use for convenient purposes. Then you can access the file using methods like `read` or `write`.